# How to use BigDecimal in Kotlin Multiplatform?

Tags: kotlin, bigdecimal, kotlin-multiplatform

I followed the tutorial https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/native/mpp-ios-android.html, then I successfully create the folders of androidmain, iosmain and commonmain.
However when I want to implement the datatype BigDecimal in the commonmain. It won't work. I need the decimal dataype for the currency.

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for `BigDecimal` in the Kotlin common code (yet).
You may have a look at the related thread
https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/multiplatform-bigdecimal-implementation/5631

You may create your own implementation for such a class with `expect` and `actual` keywords.
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/platform-specific-declarations.html

The idea is as follows:

- you declare `expect` declarations for the `BigDecimal` type in common code
- you use the `actual` annotations at every platform to supply the platform specific implementation (e.g. JVM's BigDecimal class)

Answer (score 1):

I know that the question is old, but, in case anyone stumbles upon this topic, I made a KigDecimal library that implements BigDecimal and BigInteger for kotlin multiplatform (for jvm and js). The library is distributed completely freely. Therefore, I invite everyone to supplement and expand it, if desired.

On the jvm side, BigDecimal and BigInteger are just the corresponding types from java. And on the js side is used https://www.npmjs.com/package/bigdecimal.

The main repository is located here: https://gitflic.ru/project/mikhaylutsyury/kig-decimal

There is also a mirror on github: https://github.com/YuryMikhailuts/kig-decimal

But the mirror can sometimes lag a little behind the main repository.

Comment: Great to see someone using the existing GWT implementation. Tried it. Unfortunately it is missing setScale with RoundingMode for me, will add an issue and try to help out when needed.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve ported the Android `BigDecimal` implementation to Kotlin, which makes it usable for Kotlin/Native, particularly for iOS. It cannot support Kotlin/JS though, as it depends on BoringSSL for the actual BIGNUM implementation. The code is here:

https://github.com/kendy/Kotlin-Native-BigDecimal/

Please see the [README.md](https://github.com/kendy/Kotlin-Native-BigDecimal/blob/master/README.md) on how to build it, and how to use it.

It has the same API as the Java `BigDecimal`, so you can use the `expect/ actual` as suggested in the other answer. Alternatively you can avoid the `expect/actual`, and just create a file `shared/src/iosMain/kotlin/java/math/BigDecimal.kt` in your project with content like the following:

```
package java.math

typealias BigDecimal = kendy.math.BigDecimal
```

[Of course, even with this approach, you still need to build the BigDecimal.klib & integrate it into your project as described in the README.md.]